# Php dompdf doesnt work with css

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I try to generate pdf from html with css styles ,

I use dompdf for this.
In css there are floats too.

This is my css and html code:

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();  //create object 
//load html with css
$dompdf->loadHtml('<html>
<head>
<style>
#first_head,#second_head,#content_invoice{width: 100%;}
.has-65 {
    width: 65%;
    float:left;
}
#product_invoice_table tr th:last-child, #product_invoice_table tr td:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}
.has-35 {
    width: 35%;
    float:right;
}
.has-55 {
    width: 55%;
}
.has-45 {
    width: 45%;
}
.clearFix{
    float:none;
    clear:both;
}
#second_head{
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#template_invoice{
    padding: 50px 80px 50px 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000!important;
    font-family: Arial,serif!important;
}
#content_invoice{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

#product_total_info{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 100px;
}...
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="template_invoice">
    <div id="first_head">
        <div id="logo_invoice" class="has-65">
            <img src="logo.PNG" width="280px">
        </div>
        <div id="main_header_info" class="has-35">
       mandelaugengroup gmbh
Schaffhauserstrasse 611
CH - 8052 Zürich
Tel.: +41 79 205 05 05
info@babboe.ch
www.babboe.ch
MWST/UID-Nr. CHE-254.427.754
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
    <div id="second_head">
        <div id="lead_address" class="has-65">
            <span id="lead_name">ghmgmgm</span><br>
            <span id="lead_street">mhgmhm</span><br>
            <span id="lead_postcode_city">mbmbmjggjg</span><br>
        </div>
         <div id="lead_invoice_info" class="has-35">
            <div class="span_padding_invoice">
            <span class="invoice_main_span">Rechnungs-Nr.</span>
            <span id="lead_rechnungs_nr" class="right-clmn-span">jghghjgh</span>
            <br>
            </div>
            <div class="span_padding_invoice">
            <span class="invoice_main_span">Kunden-Nr.</span>
            <span id="lead_kunder_nr" class="right-clmn-span">ghjgvj</span>
            <br>
                </div>
            <div class="span_padding_invoice">
            <span class="invoice_main_span">Datum</span>
            <span id="invoice_datum" class="right-clmn-span">hhhhhhh</span>
            <br>
                </div>
            <div class="span_padding_invoice">
            <span class="invoice_main_span">Fallig am</span>
            <span id="invoice_falling_am" class="right-clmn-span">bjbbb</span>
            <br>
                </div>
            <div class="span_padding_invoice lead_total_container">
                <span class="invoice_main_span total_bold">Total</span>
                <span id="lead_total" class="right-clmn-span">iljkkj</span>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content_invoice">
    ...
        <table id="product_invoice_table" width="100%">
      ....
        </table>
     </div>
     <div class="has-65"></div>
   <div id="product_total_info" class="has-35">
        <div class="span_padding_invoice lead_total_container">
        <span class="invoice_main_span">Total exkl.MWST</span>
        <span class="right-clmn-span">CHF <span id="total_sum"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="span_padding_invoice">
        <span class="invoice_main_span" id="mwst_num"></span>
        <span class="right-clmn-span">CHF <span id="total_percant"></span></span>
        <br>
            </div>
        <div class="span_padding_invoice lead_total_container_bold">
        <span class="invoice_main_span">Total</span>
        <span class="right-clmn-span">CHF <span id="total_end"></span></span>
            <br>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_invoice">
  ...
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("hello.pdf");
```

But my css doesnt work good. I add css as  .
I get this result:

[image: result]

So how can I solve this problem?
Maybe I must set some settings for my css or settinhs for page?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Was it the float attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that `float` is the cause of the problem

> Depending on the dompdf version you can use `def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", true);` in `dompdf_config.inc.php` but this is not a good practice

I would suggest to use `display:inline-block` or even `position:absolute` which are fully compatible.